# How To Install and Configure ImageMagick for PHP and Wordpres on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: ssh, yum, imagemagick, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I've installed a fresh Wordpress site on my Amazon Linux AMI following the setup instructions listed on the EC2 Tutorials section i.e. "Hosting a WordPress Blog with Amazon Linux". I'm also using the "WP S3 Offload" plugin so that I can use S3 to store my media files, rather then housing them on the EC2 instance. Ok, all that said the "WP S3 Offload" plugin is showing an error/warning message that says, *"Image Manipulation Library Missing — Looks like you don't have an image manipulation library installed on this server and configured with PHP. You may run into trouble if you try to edit images. Please setup GD or ImageMagick."*

I know I could search `yum` packages by typing `sudo yum search ImageMagick` in my EC2 instances terminal, which is what I did... and a list of available packages came up. Since I have PHP v5.6 installed, I decided to use the `php56-pecl-imagick` package via `sudo yum install -y php56-pecl-imagick`. I assumed that would take care of the problem but the "WP S3 Offload" plugin is still showing that same warning about the *Image Manipulation Library Missing*.

1. Did I install/configure the ImageMagick package correctly?
2. Is there another or more optimal way to install the ImageMagick package?
3. How can I test if the package is installed or not?
4. Am I missing any other packages?

Comment: Did it also install ImageMagick itself, i.e. are the binaries present? Check what  is returned by `convert --version` and best also provide the output of `rpm -qa|sort|grep -i magick`

Comment: So is the full command I need to run `convert --version rpm -qa|sort|grep -i magick` or do I run them as separate commands i.e. run `convert --version` and then run `rpm -qa|sort|grep -i magick`?

Comment: Those are separate commands.

Comment: Hey @doktor5000 that worked and it appears as if I did install it correctly when I typed ```convert --version``` I received a response of ```Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2015-10-08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP``` and when I ran ```rpm -qa|sort|grep -i magick``` I received a response of ```ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-10.18.amzn1.x86_64 php56-pecl-imagick-3.1.2-2.14.amzn1.x86_64```. So it appears as if I installed everything correctly. If you can anwer the question with your previous response, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: +Corey Added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer as it seems to have helped:

You should ensure that ImageMagick itself is installed, i.e. make sure that the actual binaries are present. Check what is returned by `convert --version` and also provide the output of
`rpm -qa|sort|grep -i magick` which should confirm that ImageMagick and php56-pecl-imagick are installed.

I've tested with a recent CentOS installation, and there `php-pecl-imagick` already requires ImageMagick, but it seemed to be missing on your installation.